# iphone debugging error

Tags: iphone, ios4

can anybody tell me the reason why I m getting this error:

conversion to non-scalar type requested

Thanks...

Comment: need some more details. probably some code will help

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your are trying to cast or assign a scalar type (int, float, double) to a object or pointer but not easy to know without seeing code.